# Why isn't copy-initalization performed on reference initialization here?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Given

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test {


public:
    Test() {

        cout << "Default constructor" << endl;
    }

    Test(const Test &) {

        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Test && t1 = Test();
}
```

Why is it that when t1 is initialized, the copy constructor of Test isn't used? From reading [reference initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) it appears that `object` is a temporary which should invoke copy-initialization. Or is this a class type expression? If that is the case can someone define what a class type expression is (I'm having a hard time googling that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Test && t1 = Test();` does not create a reference to a copy, instead `Test()` produces a temporary object and `t1` is bound directly to that temporary (and the temporary's lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the `t1`).

---

> 2) When a **named rvalue reference variable** is declared with an initializer
>
> Otherwise, if the reference is either **rvalue reference** or lvalue reference to const:
>
> If object is an xvalue, a **class prvalue**, an array prvalue, or a function lvalue type that is either T or derived from T, equally or less cv-qualified, then **the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression** or to its base subobject.

Comment: Is the object an xvalue or a class prvalue? I thought constructor expressions don't have value associated with them since they don't return anything.

Comment: prvalue I believe. All expressions are exactly one of lvalue, xvalue or prvalue. A constructor doesn't `return` anything, but a constructor expression still has the constructed object as its value. The constructor expression is not simply a function call to the constructor, just like using `new` is not simply a function call to the allocation function. The compiler does extra stuff.

Comment: But since a prvalue has the properties of an rvalue, I don't see how it could be bound to an lvalue in an example like `Test t`

Comment: A declaration `Test t;` doesn't create an rvalue or bind any rvalue to to anything. Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: That should be fine since the default constructor has 0 arguments

Comment: `Test t;` is fine, it's just not an expression, and it declares an lvalue variable. No rvalues are involved.

Comment: Sorry my bad, what about `Test t = Test()`? That looks like an expression that binds to an lvalue t

Comment: @edaniels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Comment: @edaniels `Test t = Test();` does do copy construction. However you may not actually see the copy constructor run due to copy elision. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a9bab2684268b84). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).